# Zoomed in ipad simulator?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios-simulator

For some reason, when I run my app, the game is zoomed in in the ipad simulator. I have to use a scroll bar at the right in order to move the screen up or down. The only way I've managed to get the entire thing looking normal is to scale it to 75% but I want to keep it at 100%. Does anyone know what the problem is and how I can fix it?

Comment: Command + 1, Command + 2, Command + 3

Comment: If you want to keep it at 100% then either get a larger screen for your computer or put up with the scrolling.

Comment: You can adjust the simulator size by using window>scale>50% from your simulator options

Comment: The simulator is zoomed even when there's plenty of space on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same. There's plenty of room for the simulator to not be zoomed, but it is, like so:

[image]

The best solution I've found is to got to `Window` -> `Zoom All`. I have this bound to a keyboard shortcut so I can quickly fix it, but I haven't been able to find a way to make it not open zoomed.